# Is it possible (and worth it) to store non-const program data in FLASH rather than in RAM?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, programming

I'm the situation that my program stack variables take 24kB, and global variables take 27kB. My MCU's SRAM is only 40kB.

Would it be possible to store part of the data anywhere else? For example, in FLASH memory.

Comment: Flash memory is much slower, usually requires whole blocks to be read or written, and is subject to wear (after a number of writes the block becomes invalid). It is also usually not accessible by code in the same way as RAM. So even though you could use flash to store data, you’ll usually have to rewrite the parts of the code that use it to do so. You either have to optimise your code to use less memory or switch to an MCU with more memory.

Comment: Can you tell us what MCU you are using, though? Some alllow external RAM to be added.

Comment: Why would you save _non-const_ data in flash? That will involve a flash loader, erasing, maybe checksums. The only reason for doing so is when you wish to preserve data after power down. Though if your _stack_ takes 24kb then there is very likely some serious optimization work to do.

Comment: @jcaron Sure, it's MPC5604P from NXP

Comment: @Lundin the situation is not that clear ... it was code directly generated from matlab/simulink. No human work here

Comment: @yeuop Understandable. Like High Level Synthesis for FPGA, not a surprise when such tools generate code that is worse than an optimized one by an order of magnitude or more.

Comment: @devnull Exactly...

Comment: The data sheet says about flash "Multiple-mapping support and mapping-based block access timing (up to 31 additional cycles) allowing use for emulation of other memory types". So it may be _possible_ to use flash to emulate RAM, but at the cost of a **huge** performance penalty. If you are crunching numbers, probably not a good idea.

Comment: @jcaron You are right, thanks for time spent on reading datasheet. I'm kinda newbie and I'm still getting surprised what things can be found in datasheets ;)

Comment: Is this before or after optimization? Are you using Codewarrior or something else? MPC56 is _truly horrible_ when it comes to data flash emulation, it got huge erase sizes of it's pages - basically it doesn't got data flash but only program flash.

Comment: Oh wait! Heh... In case of Codewarrior... you _are_ aware of this little tweak called RAM build vs internal flash, yes? If you are doing the RAM build, then that's the reason for all your problems and the fix is super easy - just switch to flash build.

Comment: @Lundin Yes I am using codeWarrior, but I use casual FLASH build, so unfortunately problem is not there. But thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @yeuop Too bad, it would have been a very easy fix :)

Comment: But anyway, you should diagnose what exactly is taking up all that space. Check the .map file and see if you find anything fishy getting stored in .data or .bss (and .sdata, .sbss and so on, the PPC ABI for these parts is rather complex).

Comment: There's probably a mismatch between the chosen MCU and the tools used. MCUs with limited memory like this one prefer hand-crafted code rather than code generated by other tools usually targeted at much more capable platforms. If there aren't any obvious things to fix, you should probably consider switching to a more capable platform, you'll save a lot of time in the longer run.

Comment: MPC560xE family apparently got parts up to 96kb so that would be the first choice, if it got the necessary peripherals. What's very nice with these is the ECC, no mucking around with manual CRC crap.

Comment: @yeuop please avoid adding details in comments. Instead **edit your question** to include them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since matlab/simulink generated code is being used, performance doesn't seem to be an issue. If a development kit is the basis for the development, with access to IO pins, a SPI SRAM may be an option:

Just an [example](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22126E.pdf). Chose one with compatible specs (voltage etc).

Comment: External SRAM is usually not allowed in automotive applications however. There should be other MPC56xx parts to port to instead. MPC5643 that I'm using myself got 128kb RAM, though that one's been around for a while so there might be other parts recommended for new designs.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the feedback. Choosing another uC would be my first option too if changing (or tweaking) the development tool is not an option.

Comment: @Lundin I didn't know that tho... Why is it not allowed? Just for curiosity

Comment: @yeuop Mainly because it's another thing that can introduce errors from EMI.

Comment: @Lundin thank you!